# Is the usage of WeakRefence here practical?

Tags: java

**Note:** The below referenced `Provider` is the root of an extension so to speak. They *provide* various things and as such when they are unloaded/removed so should all of their functionality/objects that is has provided.

So what I want is to allow for `Provider` to be in a way weakly reachable. I don't **want** the GC to simply collect it when I'm low on memory or just because it's not used a lot. What I'm looking for is that when said Provider is unloaded, that all of it's counter-parts are then perhaps weakly reachable etc. The reasoning behind this is say a `Provider` has provided a particular handler, well if the provider is gone, that means the handler should no longer be needed and should be dropped.

**What I'm asking in a nut shell is:** What is the best way for objects that have been provided by another object to be "dropped" (set to be removed/weakly reachable/GC'd)?

I have read up on strong, soft, weak, and phantom references. Soft/weak references are looking nice, although I'm not quite sure if they are *really* what I'm looking for (see above- I don't want the provider to be GC'd at will, but instead have what it has been provided be GC'd etc when the provider is no longer around). Events are an option, although I was interested in knowing if I could do it on a different level so that developers couldn't (*easily*) jump into the event and prevent the GC'ing of particular objects (which would prevent other objects from getting GC'd).

Thanks for any and all help/insight!

Comment: It sounds like what you want is the ordinary GC behavior: you don't want the provider to be garbage-collected as long as it's reachable, and you don't want its counterparts to be garbage-collectable as long as the provider is around, and so on. Nothing in your description seems to require weak references (or any other special GC-related features).

Comment: @ruakh Well, see the thing is yes, GC will take care of the provider perfectly fine, although I **want** to have the objects that the provider *provided* be removed from the collections that they've been stored in. I've used a `WeakHashMap<Provider, Set<SomeProvidedObject>>` since AFAIK this will ensure once the key is weakly reachable it will remove the pair. Although for removing- ah I see, right GC will take care of individual references (ie: A field of type Provider in some object) so to make a weak/soft reference of it would be pointless, yes?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't edit your post (including title) when your issue is resolved. Instead, accept the answer that solved the problem, or, if you found the answer yourself, write a self-answer.

Comment: @chrylis There was no answer to accept- rather a comment that answered my question. I don't really have an answer to write up because it is just merely a "noted- I don't need anything I'm good". Should I just post that in a self-answer?

Comment: The best option is probably a weak reference. I'd just write an answer mentioning the conclusions you've come to, even if there's not a simple clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that in my particular situation I do not need the addition of any references other than the normal strong references and my already used [WeakHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) collections.